# Order sets of numbers for maximum distance

Tags: algorithm, sorting, numbers, set, scoring

You have (up to 100) *distinct* sets of (2-4) numbers. The order of the sets or numbers in the sets does not matter. The highest number relates to the number of sets and goes up to 30. Like:

{1 2 3 4}
{1 2 3 5}
{1 2 3}
{1 2 4 5}
{6 2 4}
{6 7 8 9}
{6 7 9}
{7 8 9}
{2 4 8 9}

The goal is, to arrange these sets in a particular order, where two successive sets do not contain a common number. That is

{1 2 3 4}
{2 4 8 9}

is bad (because of the 2). And

{1 2 3 4}
{6 7 8 9}

is good.

Of course, especially in the given example, this is not possible for the whole set of sets. But the number of sets which violate the rules should approximately be minimized.

I assume, some brute-force + scoring algorithm is not feasible with the relatively large number of sets.
Do you have any other ideas or hints for a deterministic algorithm to solve this problem?

Do you think, a shuffle + score algorithm could find decent solutions (in some restricted time frame, like 5 seconds, standard computer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a graph out of your sets, where vertices are the sets and there are edges between them if they can be successive in the list (i.e. have no common element).

On this you can run any algorithm that finds a [Hamiltonian path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path), which is an NP-hard problem.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Quick answer, "easy" solution.
Pretty straightforward but, I guess, infeasible for 100 edges. Good to know, instead of wasting time for a deterministic solution.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that a Hamiltonian path does not always exist here, which would make the algorithm even more complex (to find an optimal solution).

Comment: Randomized algorithms for Hamiltonian path are usually greedy, so you will get "decent paths" as intermediate results. Whenever the greedy algorithm runs into a dead end, you can decide whether to return the current path, or keep on trying.

Comment: Also there's a bunch of theorems that can tell you whether there is a Hamilton path or not based on graph connectivity, vertex degrees, etc. Checking that before can help you make the decision.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think that possible if algorithm is properly designed. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Example:_Using_inversion_to_find_an_approximate_solution) is the example of solving similar problem for 60 "sets" in 2.7*10^5 operations. That number seems adequate for an average modern computer.